# Regular Expression UserName maker

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am creating a user login page in which user can input his/her name as below:
**username** must start with alphabet as minimum 5 to 30 times, can also be 5 to 10 times, 5 to 23 times but the maximum must be under 30 characters count **THEN** ***follow or not follow*** by [0-9] digits 1 to 10 times, digit can also be 1 to 5 times or 1 to 9 times but the maximum number must be under 10 digits count.

Sample:

1. dksdfekpwef
2. askdkindolsiiejd12324434
3. kksdq9

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: "*I want to do X*" is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *regex* would do it ...

```
[a-zA-Z]{5,30}\d{0,10}
```

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/bsAGpM/1)**